# Why does attempted Union structure cause System.ExecutionEngineException?

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr, union

I tried to experiment with the ability of .NET to support unions using the code below, but it causes a System.ExecutionengineException in .NET 2.0 and FatalExecutionEngineError in .NET 4.0 with the message:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal
>   error. The address of the error was at
>   0x738b3138, on thread 0x1080. The
>   error code is 0xc0000005. This error
>   may be a bug in the CLR or in the
>   unsafe or non-verifiable portions of
>   user code. Common sources of this bug
>   include user marshaling errors for
>   COM-interop or PInvoke, which may
>   corrupt the stack.

I agree that this code should not work, but I didn't expect this kind of exception.  Is this a .NET bug?

```
Class POLine
  Public price As Decimal
  Public VendorItem As String
End Class

Class SOLine
  Public price As Decimal
  Public Required As DateTime
End Class

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
Structure LineRef
  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)> _
  Public poLine As POLine
  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)> _
  Public soLine As SOLine
End Structure

Sub Main()
  Dim lr As New LineRef
  lr.poLine = New POLine With {.price = 1.23D, .VendorItem = "X22"}
  lr.soLine = New SOLine With {.price = 3.14D, .Required = DateTime.Now}
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lr.soLine.price, lr.soLine.Required)
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lr.poLine.price, lr.poLine.VendorItem)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unverifiable, since object references shouldn't overlap, which your `poLine` and `soLine` fields clearly do.  As section 10.7 of Partition II of the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) states:

> Offset values shall be non-negative. It is possible to overlap fields in this way, though offsets occupied by an object reference shall not overlap with offsets occupied by a built-in value type or a part of another object reference. While one object reference can completely overlap another, this is unverifiable.

You can further check that your code is unverifiable using PEVerify (run peverify.exe against your executable from the Visual Studio command prompt) - it will confirm that the code contains an error.

Therefore it is not surprising that you see an exception at runtime, and the exception that you're seeing seems perfectly reasonable to me (the text indicates that it may be caused by unverifiable code) - what leads you to expect different behavior?

Comment: I didn't realize there was a category of code called "unverifiable" in .NET / CLI. Is that somewhere between managed and unsafe -- a category of code called "unverifiable"? Do I recall correctly that you can prevent unsafe code from being included in a project if it is not included within an "unsafe" block? Is there anything (similar perhaps) outside of PEVerify that deals with unverifiable code? Are there other examples of unverifiable code that is not quite "unsafe"?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - I think that "unsafe" and "unverifiable" are synonymous.  It is indeed confusing that the use of the `StructLayout` attribute is allowed without the `/unsafe` switch in C# and VB.NET (in contrast, in F# it at least generates a warning).

Comment: The CLI specification only uses the term "unverifiable". "Unsafe" is a C# thing, and is defined solely by the C# spec. The two terms overlap in practice, but they are not identical - as this question shows, CLI-unverifiable code might not fall into the category of C#-unsafe. C#-unsafe, on the other hand, is always unverifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the second field offset to 80 (or higher) will solve your problem.

Though I have no idea what all the structure layout and offsets are, what do you even use them for?

Edit: Oh just noticed your question is why it gives this error and not what causing it, and the 4.0 net says the error could be caused by corrupting the stack, and you declare a variable in the same offset as the first one which... corrupts the stack. There is no problem with that error.

Comment: I thought managed code was smarter than that and didn't allow corruption (which would be considered unsafe) without explicitly predicating it as unsafe. That's why I ran this test, to see how it would handle an attempt at accessing this structure in a potentially unsafe way.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping two reference types to the same offset. That by itself is not illegal as long as you don't try to use both at the same time, which is precisely what you are trying to do here.

It is not a bug, the usage you make of the union is simply wrong and the system rightfully complains. On a native environment, the pointer would have been silently overwrote.

Comment: That's exactly my point.  As I said, the code should not work, but the kind of exception it is throwing doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Blue - I see your point; I misunderstood the question. I'm curious, where is the exception thrown? When trying to use the overwritten instance or as soon as you overwrite it? If the later, then the code is still technically safe, as it becomes impossible to overwrite the other instance without the managed environment to notice immediately and throw a fatal error.

Comment: It happens on the second WriteLine.

Comment: Damn. It is quite unsafe then.